# if 2nd image uploaded the 1st image will remove and 2nd image will come in the place of this 1st image how to achieve that in react native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I have created a form in react native. I have 2 icons for user one is to upload pan card image and 2nd is to upload adhar card image lets say user have upload 1st image of pan card and now his image is not properly set now he want to upload 2nd image from same option. when user will upload 2nd image on 1st image . 1st image will remove automatically. and in the place of that image 2nd image will come.  so haw can I achieve that please help.

here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Button,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  alert,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function Add({navigation}) {

  // const { height } = Dimensions.get("window");
  // const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");

  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = useState(null);
  const [galleryPermission, setGalleryPermission] = useState(null);
  const [showCamera, setShowCamera] = useState(false);
  const [camera, setCamera] = useState(null);
  const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState([]);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
  const [imageArray, setImageArray] = useState([]);

  const [PIMGError, setPImgError] = useState([]);
  const [PIMG, setPImg] = useState('');
  const [GIMGError, setGImgError] = useState([]);
  const [GIMG, setGImg] = useState('');
  const [AIMGError, setAImgError] = useState([]);
  const [AIMG, setAImg] = useState('');

  const permisionFunction = async () => {
    // here is how you can get the camera permission
    const cameraPermission = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
    console.log('camera permission:', cameraPermission.status);

    setCameraPermission(cameraPermission.status === 'granted');

    const imagePermission = await ImagePicker.getMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    console.log('permission:', imagePermission.status);

    setGalleryPermission(imagePermission.status === 'granted');

    if (
      imagePermission.status !== 'granted' &&
      cameraPermission.status !== 'granted'
    ) {
      alert('Permission for media access needed.');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    permisionFunction();
  }, []);

  
  const validateInputs = () =>{
    if (!/[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}/.test(PIMG))
    {
        setPImgError('Please Insert PAN Card Image')
        return;
    }
    if (!/^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}$/.test(GIMG)) 
  {
    setGImgError('Please Insert GST Card Image')
        return;
  }
  if (!/^[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}$/.test(AIMG)) 
  {
    setAImgError('Please Insert Adhar Card Image')
        return;
  }
    else {
      Alert.alert("All fields validated")
      return;
    }
  }

  const handlePIMG = (text) => {
      setPImgError('')
      setPImg(text)
  }
  const handleGIMG = (text) => {
    setGImgError('')
    setGImg(text)
}
const handleAIMG = (text) => {
  setAImgError('')
  setAImg(text)
}


  const takePicture = async () => {
    if (camera) {
      const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(null);
      console.log(data.uri);
      setImageUri(data.uri);
      setImageArray([...imageArray, data.uri]);
      setShowCamera(false);
    }
  };

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result.uri);
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImageArray([...imageArray, result.uri]);
    }
  };

  return (

    <View style={{flex: 1}}>

    <View style={styles.header}>
     <Ionicons style={{paddingLeft:20}} name="arrow-back" size={40} 
    color="black"  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("FormItems")} />
    <Text style={{fontSize:20, paddingLeft: 70, paddingTop: 10}}>KYC Details</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.container}>
      {showCamera && (
        <Camera ref={(ref) => setCamera(ref)} style={{ flex: 1 }} type={type} />
      )}
      {showCamera && <Button title={'Click'} onPress={takePicture} />}
      {!showCamera && (
        <>
          <View
            style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop:30 }}>
              <Text style={{fontSize:20, color:'white', marginRight:35, marginLeft:20}}>Insert PAN Card Image</Text>
              <Entypo name="camera" size={24} color="black"  onPress={() => {
                  setShowCamera(true);
                }} />
              <Entypo style={{marginLeft:10}} name="folder-images" size={24} color="black"  onPress={pickImage}  />
            </View>
          </View>

          <View
            style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
           <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop:30 }}>
           <Text style={{fontSize:20, color:'white', marginRight:35, marginLeft:20}}>Insert GST Card Image</Text>
              <Entypo name="camera" size={24} color="black"  onPress={() => {
                  setShowCamera(true);
                }} />
              <Entypo style={{marginLeft:10}} name="folder-images" size={24} color="black"  onPress={pickImage}  />
            </View>
          </View>

          <View
            style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop:30 }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:20, color:'white', marginRight:20, marginLeft:20}}>Insert Adhar Card Image</Text>
              <Entypo name="camera" size={24} color="black"  onPress={() => {
                  setShowCamera(true);
                }} />
              <Entypo style={{marginLeft:10}} name="folder-images" size={24} color="black"  onPress={pickImage}  />
            </View>
          </View>

          {imageArray.length > 0 && (
            <View style={{ height: 110 }}>
              <FlatList
                horizontal
                data={imageArray}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <Image
                    source={{ uri: item }}
                    style={{
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      borderRadius: 10,
                      margin: 5,
                    }}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </View>
          )}
        </>
      )}
      <Button style={styles.inputStyleB}
          title="Submit"
          color="#808080"
          onPress={() => validateInputs()}
        />
    </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    // marginTop: 30,
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: "rgb(247, 146, 57)",
      // alignItems: 'center',
      // justifyContent: 'center',
      paddingTop: 15,
  },
  fixedRatio: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  header:{
    flexDirection:'row'
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is Expo Snack Link for that project [Link to Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@darkkiller/arrogant-popsicle)

I have made many changes to the code and create a state for storing image type like `PAN` or `GST` or `Aadhar` and according to this type set `image.uri` property to `imageArray`.

I have also removed `FlatList` from code beacause i have changed `ImageArray` State to object

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Button,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  alert,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function Add({ navigation }) {
  // const { height } = Dimensions.get("window");
  // const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");

  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = useState(null);
  const [galleryPermission, setGalleryPermission] = useState(null);
  const [showCamera, setShowCamera] = useState(false);
  const [camera, setCamera] = useState(null);
  const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState([]);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
  const [imageArray, setImageArray] = useState({
    PAN: null,
    GST: null,
    Aadhar: null,
  });
  const [imageType, setImageType] = useState('');

  const [PIMGError, setPImgError] = useState([]);
  const [PIMG, setPImg] = useState('');
  const [GIMGError, setGImgError] = useState([]);
  const [GIMG, setGImg] = useState('');
  const [AIMGError, setAImgError] = useState([]);
  const [AIMG, setAImg] = useState('');

  const permisionFunction = async () => {
    // here is how you can get the camera permission
    const cameraPermission = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
    console.log('camera permission:', cameraPermission.status);

    setCameraPermission(cameraPermission.status === 'granted');

    const imagePermission = await ImagePicker.getMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    console.log('permission:', imagePermission.status);

    setGalleryPermission(imagePermission.status === 'granted');

    if (
      imagePermission.status !== 'granted' &&
      cameraPermission.status !== 'granted'
    ) {
      alert('Permission for media access needed.');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    permisionFunction();
  }, []);

  const validateInputs = () => {
    if (!/[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}/.test(PIMG)) {
      setPImgError('Please Insert PAN Card Image');
      return;
    }
    if (
      !/^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}$/.test(GIMG)
    ) {
      setGImgError('Please Insert GST Card Image');
      return;
    }
    if (!/^[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}$/.test(AIMG)) {
      setAImgError('Please Insert Adhar Card Image');
      return;
    } else {
      Alert.alert('All fields validated');
      return;
    }
  };

  const handlePIMG = (text) => {
    setPImgError('');
    setPImg(text);
  };
  const handleGIMG = (text) => {
    setGImgError('');
    setGImg(text);
  };
  const handleAIMG = (text) => {
    setAImgError('');
    setAImg(text);
  };

  const takePicture = async () => {
    if (camera) {
      const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(null);
      console.log(data.uri);
      setImageUri(data.uri);
      const newImageArr = imageArray;
      if (imageType === 'PAN') {
        newImageArr.PAN = data.uri;
      }
      if (imageType === 'GST') {
        newImageArr.GST = data.uri;
      }
      if (imageType === 'Aadhar') {
        newImageArr.Aadhar = data.uri;
      }
      setImageArray({ ...newImageArr });
      setShowCamera(false);
      setImageType('');
    }
  };

  const pickImage = async (type) => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result.uri);
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      const newImageArr = imageArray;
      if (type === 'PAN') {
        newImageArr.PAN = result.uri;
      }
      if (type === 'GST') {
        newImageArr.GST = result.uri;
      }
      if (type === 'Aadhar') {
        newImageArr.Aadhar = result.uri;
      }
      setImageArray({ ...newImageArr });
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Ionicons
          style={{ paddingLeft: 20 }}
          name="arrow-back"
          size={40}
          color="black"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('FormItems')}
        />
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, paddingLeft: 70, paddingTop: 10 }}>
          KYC Details
        </Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.container}>
        {showCamera && (
          <Camera
            ref={(ref) => setCamera(ref)}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            type={type}
          />
        )}
        {showCamera && <Button title={'Click'} onPress={takePicture} />}
        {!showCamera && (
          <>
            <View
              style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 30 }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: 'white',
                    marginRight: 35,
                    marginLeft: 20,
                  }}>
                  Insert PAN Card Image
                </Text>
                <Entypo
                  name="camera"
                  size={24}
                  color="black"
                  onPress={() => {
                    setShowCamera(true);
                    setImageType('PAN');
                  }}
                />
                <Entypo
                  style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
                  name="folder-images"
                  size={24}
                  color="black"
                  onPress={() => {
                    pickImage("PAN");
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            </View>

            <View
              style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 30 }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: 'white',
                    marginRight: 35,
                    marginLeft: 20,
                  }}>
                  Insert GST Card Image
                </Text>
                <Entypo
                  name="camera"
                  size={24}
                  color="black"
                  onPress={() => {
                    setShowCamera(true);
                    setImageType('GST');
                  }}
                />
                <Entypo
                  style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
                  name="folder-images"
                  size={24}
                  color="black"
                  onPress={() => {
                    pickImage("GST");
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            </View>

            <View
              style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 30 }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: 'white',
                    marginRight: 20,
                    marginLeft: 20,
                  }}>
                  Insert Adhar Card Image
                </Text>
                <Entypo
                  name="camera"
                  size={24}
                  color="black"
                  onPress={() => {
                    setShowCamera(true);
                    setImageType('Aadhar');
                  }}
                />
                <Entypo
                  style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
                  name="folder-images"
                  size={24}
                  color="black"
                  onPress={() => {
                    pickImage("Aadhar");
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            </View>

            {imageArray.PAN && (
              <Image
                source={{ uri: imageArray.PAN }}
                style={{
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  borderRadius: 10,
                  margin: 5,
                }}
              />
            )}

            {imageArray.GST && (
              <Image
                source={{ uri: imageArray.GST }}
                style={{
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  borderRadius: 10,
                  margin: 5,
                }}
              />
            )}

            {imageArray.Aadhar && (
              <Image
                source={{ uri: imageArray.Aadhar }}
                style={{
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  borderRadius: 10,
                  margin: 5,
                }}
              />
            )}
          </>
        )}
        <Button
          style={styles.inputStyleB}
          title="Submit"
          color="#808080"
          onPress={() => validateInputs()}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    // marginTop: 30,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(247, 146, 57)',
    // alignItems: 'center',
    // justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 15,
  },
  fixedRatio: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  header: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
});
```

Comment: If my answer solves your problem. Please upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: thanks bro thanku so much one more please i want user to not able to submit until all 3 images will fillup

Comment: i want user should not leave image field empty

Comment: @SohilShaikh simply add check of null `onSubmit`

Comment: @SohilShaikh  create a function and check `if(imageArray.PAN === null) return false`   and if false dont submit the data

Comment: create same for other 2 options

Comment: No bro I can not able to modify it means where should i put that onchange on press on image uploading

Comment: means I want to Show error so where should i show it